# Como implementar o padrão MVC em PHP

Tags: php, mvc

Sou programador novato e estou com uma certa dificuldade em montar minha estrutura MVC. Quando digo estrutura quero dizer como desenvolver um model.php um view.php e um controller.php, enfim que código desenvolver para ligá-los, fazê-los interagir uns com os outros.

Eu já sei o que *Model*, *View* e *Controller* fazem, mas quero saber o que colocar neles em termos de código. Qual é o mínimo que precisa ser feito para implementar o padrão MVC?

Comment: Eu recomendaria o Kohana como ponto de partida para fins didáticos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[O Wiki sobre a tag `mvc`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/mvc/info) pode ser um bom ponto de partida.

O MVC é um modelo teórico, um padrão de design. [Há este link do SitePoint que pode servir como um tutorial para o seu caso, em PHP](http://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/). É um pouco extenso, então não sei se vale a pena postar uma resposta inteira sobre isso.

Para aprimorar seu conhecimento, acho que também vale ir para uma solução mais bem acabada em um Framework, [como o CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/). Padrões e boas práticas já existem no Framework e este em especial exige que você escreva várias etapas manuais.

Outro ótimo Framework [é o Laravel](http://www.codeigniter.com/).

Ambos possuem várias perguntas respondidas aqui no SOpt.

Sobre sua dificuldade em elaborar soluções, o caminho é estudar, fazer os exemplos, aprender uns três Frameworks, apontar as diferenças sobre como eles resolvem os problemas, e perguntar aqui. Trazer suas dúvidas de uma forma mais específica, colocando código pronto e pedindo mais código. Não tem muito segredo.

Comment: Olha, amigo os links que me passou me ajudaram um pouco mais oquê está escrito na wiki eu já sei! oquê mais me ajudou foi o outro link o do sitepoint mas o grande problema e que sou bem iniciante em inglês! mas entendi um pouco! mas ainda não sanou minhas dúvidas por completo agurado mais respostas!

Comment: @xCoder Quais são suas dúvidas? Está muito amplo o que você tem dúvida. Poderia editar sua pergunta e detalhar mais?

Comment: sim, agora detalhei mais a pergunta!

Comment: Sobre estar com dificuldades de raciocínio lógico, talvez seja legal estudar algoritmo.

Comment: e quais ferramente (programas), e conteúdos me aconselha estudar ? para melhorar o ráciocinio!

Comment: @xCoder Coloquei mais algumas sugestões.

Comment: Ok, cigano agora ajudou bastante já ouvi falar muito bem do laravel encontrei aqui agora um ótimo conteúdo sobre ele vou estudar e desenvolver algo, mas agora preciso sanar minha ultima dúvida é sobre minha dificuldade em pensar para desenvolver sistemas poderia responder ...

Comment: @xCoder Editei novamente. Veja se te atende.

Comment: ok, me atendeu sim! mas pra mim concluir isso não existe nenhum conteúdo que possa me passar para melhorar meu ráciocinio não ? porquê como vou desenvolver uma solução se eu não consigo raciocinar ?

Comment: @xCoder O raciocínio eu já expliquei. Está no último parágrafo.

Comment: ok, obrigado está resolvido!